# Help with a proof involving normality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Prove that $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$.

We know, in order to be normal, the centers of each group need to commute with everybody. We also know, the groups are normal if every left coset is equal to the right coset.

How can we do this using these groups?

Comment: The first statement seems strange. The center consists of those elements commuting with everything in the group it is the center of. The center of a normal subgroup need not be central in the larger group (it will still be a normal subgroup of the larger group, but that is not important here).

Comment: As to the actual question, what have you tried? How have you had $A_n$ defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $|S_n:A_n|=2$ is all I want to say